# How big is too big for a view in MySQL InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, innodb

**BACKGROUND**

I'm working with a `MySQL` `InnoDB` database with 60+ tables and I'm creating different views in order to make dynamic queries fast and easier in the code. I have a couple of views with INNER JOINS (without many-to-many relationships) of `20 to 28 tables` SELECTING `100 to 120 columns` with `row count below 5,000` and it works lighting fast.

**ACTUAL PROBLEM**

I'm creating a master view with INNER JOINS (without many-to-many relationships) of `34 tables` and SELECTING about `150 columns` with `row count below 5,000` and it seems like it's too much. It takes forever to do a single SELECT. I'm wondering if I hit some kind of view-size limit and if there is any way of increasing it, or any tricks that would help me pass through this apparent limit.

It's important to note that I'm **NOT USING** `Aggregate functions` because I know about their negative impact on performance, which, by the way I'm very concerned about.

Comment: What "negative impact on performance"? E.g. sending all the data to your application server and calculating an average there, instead of calculating it in SQL, is probably going to be slower, not faster. When something is slow it's good to avoid needing the data; but if you do need the data, hacks to get around it aren't going to help things out.

Comment: Right! I'm using aggregate functions in queries I make afterwards, if I need that data, but I'm not using agreggate functions to create the views I mentioned.

Comment: It should make no difference. There's no difference between a view and a query in MySQL. MySQL does not do materialized views. If anything, views typically take a performance hit, not a buff.

Comment: (Erm, I should note that aggregates don't allow a view to use the MERGE algorithm strategy -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-algorithms.html )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view is just a named query. When you refer to a view in MySQL it just replaces the name with the actual query and run it.

It seems that you confuse it with materialized views, which are tables you create from a query. Afterwards you can query that table, and does not have to do the original query again.

Materialized views are not implemented in MySQL.

To improve the performance try to use the keyword [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) to see where you can optimize your query/view.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mySql, but isn't caching all different in a view?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: As far as I am aware MySQL may cache the execution plan for a view, but it does not cache the results or subqueries of a view.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-algorithms.html

Answer (score 5):

MySql does not use the "System R algorithm" (used by Postgresql, Oracle, and SQL Server, I think), which considers not only different merge algorithms (MySQL only has nested-loop, although you can fake a hash join by using a hash index), but also the possible ways of joining the tables and possible index combinations. The result seems to be that parsing of queries - and query execution - can be very quick upto a point, but performance can dramatically drop off as the optimizer chooses the wrong path through the data.

Take a look at your explain plans and try to see if a) the drop in performance is due to the number of columns you are returning (just do SELECT 1 or something) or b) if it is due to the optimizer choosing a table scan instead of index usage.